# ArcGIS Add-In Project to Standard Library Project

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, add-in, visual-studio

I have been developing an ArcGIS 10 Add-In tool, but requirements changed halfway through development. Fortunately, this isn't changing any of the code, but I just need to be able to compile the project as a standard COM extension instead of an Add-In.

I removed the `esriaddinx` file, and when I go to compile, it states that it is an invalid Add-In project. I haven't seen any properties within the project that declare it as an add-in project.

Does anyone know how ESRI flags their projects to compile as add-ins, and is there a way to reverse it without creating a new project and importing files?

Comment: I think it will be easier to just start over with the appropriate template and copy in the code you want to keep.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same thing. It was worth a shot, plus it would be more knowledge in the hands of others. Thanks!

Comment: The project is flagged with a particular identifier recognized by Esri, along with including a MSBuild task in the build process. Both are saved in the .csproj file but are not accessible through any UI. You can edit the .csproj file (which is in fact a MSBuild file) manually, but do so only if you have a certain level of understanding of MSBuild and how VS interacts with it.

Comment: Additionally the templates add COM registration stuff which add-in types don't have.